# Search for multiple strings in a text file and append the line(s) containing the string(s)

Tags: powershell

Problem: Scan a text file for one string, and if a line contains that string append the line, otherwise leave all other lines intact and output to a file. (This I have working perfectly)
Now, how do I get it to look for a second string without doubling the content output before i set-content?

**Real Problem:** I am creating this PowerShell script from a running CMD script, then executing it when completed. Everything has to be done top down to ensure I can build this by appending a text file. There may be up to 49 additional strings added to the script. (Which is why I'm trying to avoid temp files)

This ALMOST works, but it doubles the lines that match, if I leave the top section out it removes every line except the 2 that it finds.

```
gc C:\infile.txt |% {
   $a = "*"
   if ($_ -like "$a") {
   $_ -replace '', ''
}
   $a = "String With Spaces"
$a = $a.replace(' ','&nbsp;')
   if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
   $_ -replace 'replacethis', 'withthis' `
      -replace 'replacethisotherthing', 'withthisotherthing'
}
   $a = "StringWithoutSpaces"
$a = $a.replace(' ','&nbsp;')
   if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
   $_ -replace 'replacethis', 'withthis' `
      -replace 'replacethisotherthing', 'withthisotherthing'
}
} | sc C:\outfile.txt
```

It's easy to see how I drop each section in. The $a strings are made with vars from the cmd script.
It creates a new file with header section then dumps each string section, then when the cmd script closes it drops that last line to close the function and set content. Then it runs the script.

The way to do it properly with a **single** search string to replace. I am appending, but I know what the last chars will be one of 2 things, which is why I replace 2 items. present items on the line would be the below code.

```
gc C:\infile.txt |% {
   $a = "StringGoesHere"
   if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
   $_ -replace 'replacethis', 'withthis' `
      -replace 'replacethisotherthing', 'withthisotherthing'
} else {$_}
} | sc C:\outfile
```

Hopefully someone can help ;)

Comment: Capture the output of each replacement and then output at the end the replaced line

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: I have removed your [[tag:cmd]] tag. There is nothing whatsoever in your problem which is related to the fact that you are dynamically creating the powershell script from cmd.exe, (so people watching that tag, should not have to read this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you just need to assign the output of each replacement, then output the replaced line at the end of the loop:

```
Get-Content C:\infile.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $line = $_

    $a = "*"
    if ($_ -like "$a") {
        $line = $_ -replace '', ''
    }

    $a = "String With Spaces"
    $a = $a.replace(' ','&nbsp;')
    if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
        $line = $_ -replace 'replacethis', 'withthis' -replace 'replacethisotherthing', 'withthisotherthing'
    }

    $a = "StringWithoutSpaces"
    $a = $a.replace(' ','&nbsp;')
    if ($_ -like "*$a*") {
        $line = $_ -replace 'replacethis', 'withthis' -replace 'replacethisotherthing', 'withthisotherthing'
    }

    # output replaced line here
    $line
} | Set-Content C:\outfile.txt
```

Likely there is room for optimizations but without knowing what your data is and what you would like your data to be, its not possible to tell.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much! I removed the first section where A = * because it wasnt necessary and was only an uneducated attempt at getting the remaining lines to process in my initial guess/test phase ;P